# array containsObject problems

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I've a problem with NSMutableArray and finding objects through containsObject

I got an array looking like this:

NSMutableArray serverValue (
168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,180,179,178,177,176,175,174,173,172,171,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,
184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194) fetched from a server (this is Xcode dump)

I'm trying to find all values between 0 - 359 which are not in above array.

```
int index;
NSMutableArray *not = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
  for (index = 0; index < 360; index++) {
      if (! [serverValue containsObject:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:index] stringValue]]) {
          [not addObject:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:index] stringValue]];
      }
  }
```

I would expect the new array to have values from 0-167 and 194-359, but I get:

<__NSArrayM 0xc92de80>(
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,
51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,
101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,
126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,
164,165,166,167,

168,169,185,187,188,189,191,193,

194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,
220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255,256,257,
258,259,260,261,262,263,264,265,266,267,268,269,270,271,272,273,274,275,276,277,278,279,280,281,282,283,284,285,286,287,288,289,290,291,292,293,294,
295,296,297,298,299,300,301,302,303,304,305,306,307,308,309,310,311,312,313,314,315,316,317,318,319,320,321,322,323,324,325,326,327,328,329,330,331,
332,333,334,335,336,337,338,339,340,341,342,343,344,345,346,347,348,349,350,351,352,353,354,355,356,357,358,359) (this is a Xcode dump)

why just some values which are in the serverValue array? any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

cheers,

Comment: You know, if you want a list of all not-included numbers in a sorted list, a far more straight-forward and efficient approach would be to increment through the list and make note of the missing numbers in the order.

Comment: I would like to learn that. However, the list must remain unsorted for the remaining functions to work.

Comment: Then the second most straight-forward approach is to have, in essence, an array of Booleans and set the corresponding Boolean as you check each number in the original list.  Then walk through the Boolean array and insert elements in your new list for each un-set Boolean element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't compare with string value. Looks like serverValue have integers not string value

```
for (index = 0; index < 360; index++) {
    if (! [serverValue containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:index]]) {
        [not addObject:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:index] stringValue]];
    }
}
```

Or try this also if array have string and number both

```
for (index = 0; index < 360; index++) {
    BOOL isNeedToAdd = NO;
    if (![serverValue containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:index]] &&
        ![serverValue containsObject:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:index]stringValue]]) {
        isNeedToAdd = YES;
    }

    if (isNeedToAdd) {
        [not addObject:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:index] stringValue]];
    }
}
```

This code will see if the value exists in either number or string form. If neither is there, then add it to the result.

Comment: If this were completely true then the result would have all of the values from 168-194 instead of just a few of those.

Comment: It will give all other values except from 168-194.

Comment: But look at the output the OP gets. For some reason the output contains the values `168,169,185,187,188,189,191,193,194` when it shouldn't. So there may be some values that are numbers and some are strings.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre: rmaddy is not talking about the output of your answer. He is talking about the OP's question and your explanation. In OP's output 170-184 is missing. if your explanation is correct, then it won't happen.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre That update won't work. You will add the number version even if there is string version.

Comment: @rmaddy can you update this answer. I want to see what will be the solution.

Comment: You're right :) checking the array with the "drop-down" arrow I see that the array contains NSString and long int. The mixture is quite widely spread so I can't explain why I didn't get more wrong values in my "not" array, but this is surly a new angle to find the unlaying bug in my code.